# An efficiently computable infinite binary sequence satisfying a stronger disjunctiveness property

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms

Given a natural number $n > 1$ and an infinite binary sequence $B = b_0b_1b_2b_3\ldots$ (here $b_i$ denotes an $i$-th element of $B$), let $f_n(B)$ denote the following tuple of infinite binary sequences:

$$\begin{array}{l}
({b_0}{b_n}{b_{2n}}{b_{3n}} \ldots ,\\
{b_1}{b_{n + 1}}{b_{2n + 1}}{b_{3n + 1}} \ldots ,\\
{b_2}{b_{n + 2}}{b_{2n + 2}}{b_{3n + 2}} \ldots ,\\
{b_3}{b_{n + 3}}{b_{2n + 3}}{b_{3n + 3}} \ldots ,\\
 \ldots ,\\
{b_{n - 1}}{b_{2n - 1}}{b_{3n - 1}}{b_{4n - 1}} \ldots ).
\end{array}$$

I want to construct an infinite binary sequence $X$ such that:

1. It can be proven that $X$ itself is [disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence) on $\{0, 1\}$;
2. It can be proven that for *any* natural number $n > 1$, the corresponding tuple $f_n(X)$ does not contain identical infinite sequences (i.e. all elements of $f_n(X)$ are different);
3. It can be proven that for *any* natural number $n > 1$, all elements of $f_n(X)$ are disjunctive on $\{0, 1\}$.
4. There is an *efficient* algorithm to compute an $i$-th bit of $X$ for an arbitrary $i$ without pre-computing the previous bits.

What can be an example of such $X$ and what is an algorithm satisfying the $4$-th property?